# Laravel User Class was not found

Tags: laravel

I ran into a Laravel problem trying to access the build-in class on Laravel named 'User', basically I want to create new users. But I get the error saying this: 'Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\User'.intelephense(1009)`. What is the fix?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['status_code']);
        };

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;

        return response()->json([
            'status_code' => 200,
            'message' => 'User was saved!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```use App\Models\User;``` to import the UserClass or use ```new \App\Models\User()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to import the `User` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

// this is the default for Laravel 8+, before it was App\User
use App\Models\User; 

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['status_code']);
        };

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;

        return response()->json([
            'status_code' => 200,
            'message' => 'User was saved!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: now is working, but I just faced another problem when I try to post data is says saved but is not In the DB :?

Comment: also @Maik Lowrey

Comment: @templo glad it works! To persist your changes, add `$user->save();`

Comment: yes dude it works, both solutions worked. Thanks!